# R - Treemap Package not sorting by size

Tags: r, treemap

This has never been an issue before, but recently when I try to produce treemaps (using the [R treemap package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemap/index.html)) that have rectangles ordered by value I'm unable to do so. Rather rectangles are ordered alphabetically by index name. Have I misunderstood the recent documentation at any point or is this a non-reproducible issue (one to do with my package install)?

Reproducible example below. The resulting treemap is alphabetically ordered when I want it ordered by 'vals' size

```
library(treemap)

names <- as.character(c("a", "c", "b", "d"))
vals <- c(10, 20, 65, 5)
tree_ex <- as.data.frame(cbind(names, vals), )
tree_ex$vals <- as.numeric(as.character(tree_ex$vals))

treemap(tree_ex, index='names', vSize = "vals",
        algorithm = "pivotSize",
        sortID = "vals")
```

Comment: very strange indeed. Even the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemap/treemap.pdf) says "**By default, large
rectangles are placed top left**". But even when leaving everything as default it doesn't appear to work

Comment: The documented behavior held true for me previously so I suspect this must relate to a recent update. If others are getting the same issue I may raise it with the package author.

Comment: Are you able to down-grade to a previous version to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is broken. Reproducible example below. See also [Issue #30](https://github.com/mtennekes/treemap/issues/30) which I have just filed on github for treemap package

Code to reproduce the broken behaviour:

```
# create data set
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:12],size=seq(12,1),sort=sample(12))

# install the last version with sortID respected and plot treemap
devtools::install_github("treemap", user="mtennekes", subdir="pkg",ref="5ca7c0b562e4a60bab111752210d6aba8995f55a")
library(treemap)
treemap(df,index="A",vSize="size",algorithm="pivotSize",sortID="sort")

# install the version which breaks sortID and plot treemap
devtools::install_github("treemap", user="mtennekes", subdir="pkg",ref="d8817db2805058f6a36db9f882790681961bc052")
library(treemap)
treemap(df,index="A",vSize="size",algorithm="pivotSize",sortID="sort")
```

[image: picture with sortID example]

**UPDATE** 2016-03-23

Package fixed [Commit 0224354](https://github.com/mtennekes/treemap/commit/0224354050357ccb852cba7215ef451bc8ee44e9)